# Extracting single value from returned pair

Tags: lua

An external api call returns a pair of values:

```
('status', 'standby')
```

I thought it was possible to do an assignment like:

```
theQuery, theResponse = returnVal
```

So that the value I want (the second) ends up in theResponse, but this doesn't see to be working.

What I am really trying to test is whether theResponse = 'standby'

```
if theResponse=='standby' then …
```

Comment: Try `theResponse = returnVal[2]` just guess if `pair` is table. but may be `theQuery, theResponse = some_function()`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am not sure why (given nos' answer), but returnVal[2] didn't work, but unpack did.

Comment: Functions return a list of zero or more values, each of any type (including "nil"). You might be calling a list of two values a "pair"; or, a list of one table value with a sequence of length 2. Regardless, `('status', 'standby')` is just invalid syntax. The only place parentheses and commas can be used like that is in function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A few solutions:

You can use unpack():

```
theQuery, theResponse = unpack(returnVal)
```

Alternatively, you do it "manually"

```
theQuery = returnVal[1]
theResponse = returnVal[2]
```

Or change your check to do

```
if returnVal[2]=='standby' then …
```

If your `returnVal` is a table with 2 values, there is no automatic unpacking in Lua, you cannot simply do `theQuery, theResponse = returnVal`

### More explanation:

But quite related to this is that in Lua you can have a function returning multiple values, and its return values can be autumatlically unpacked, e.g.

```
function myfunc() 
    return 1,2
end
```

If you do `a, b = myfunc()` , `a` would be assigned 1 and `b` assigned 2

If you do just `a = myfunc()` `a` would be assigned 1 and 2 would be discarded.

Note that this is different from doing:

```
function myotherfunc() 
    return {1,2}
end
```

Here `myotherfunc` is returning a single value, which is a table containing 2 values.

If you now do  `a, b = myfunc()` , `a` would be assigned the table {1,2} and `b` would be `nil`. There is no unpacking of the returned table.

Comment: Thank you.  That did what I wanted and I appreciate the extra explanation.